# JavaScript async/await function not working properly

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, axios

- Part I

so I have the following code =>

```
let array = [];

await objElements.forEach( async(element) => {
  let results = await axios.get('backend_route', {params: element});
  results.data.forEach(result => {
    array.push(result);

    console.log(result);
    console.log(array);
//  here the `result` variable is printed with the desired value and the array shows all the `result` singles values on it
  });
});

console.log(array);
// But here, like if I would like to return the array at the end, it is empty :(
```

This is on JavaScript ES6 btw, if you have any possible solution any help is appreciated, thanks!

- Part II

Thanks for answering the previous question, I have been reading from Promises and still cannot figure out the new problem I have, so the code goes as following =>

```
const promise = array.map(async(item) => {
  // here for each `item` I'm doing a call to the backend.
  let response = await axios.get('route_to_backend', {params: item});
  console.log(response);

  /*When I try to get the response from the backend, it always send me
  the response for the last `item` of the array, example: if the
  array is [12, 67, 95, 06], it will make the request to the backend 4
  times (length of the array) and always with the last item of the
  array (in this example `06`) :(*/
});

//Finally as per the example I was provided
await Promise.all(promise);
```

Thanks a lot for your answers (Y)

Comment: can you post a executable snippet instead [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You're console.logging `array` syncronously but not waiting for the results that you get from your async function

Comment: you need to use a promise

Comment: async function f() {
    let array = [];
    for(let i=0; i<objElements.length; i++){
        let results = await axios.get('backend_route', {params: element});
        results.data.forEach(result => {
            array.push(result);
            console.log(result);
            console.log(array);
            //  here the `result` variable is printed with the desired value and the array shows all the `result` singles values on it
        });
    }
    console.log(array);
}

You can use like this.

Comment: You can also use `forof` loop for this.`let array = [];
for(let element of objElements){
  let results = await axios.get('backend_route', {params: element});
  for(let result of results.data) {
    array.push(result);

    console.log(result);
    console.log(array);
} }

console.log(array);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`await objElements.forEach( async(element) => {` won't actually await the inner async function.

What you really want to do is something more like:

```
const promises = objElements.map(async (element) => {...});
const results = await Promise.all(promises);
```

This creates a list of promises with `.map` and then awaits the `Promise.all` joining of them.

`results` should be an array with whatever the promises resolved with, ie whatever your internal async function returns